# Java servlet read a file and send it as response

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm trying to write a servlet which will read (download) file from a remote location and simply send it as response, acting more-or-less like a proxy to hide the actual file from getting downloaded. I'm from a PHP background where I can do it as simply as calling [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

Any handy way to achieve this goal using servlet/jsp?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

How about this one?
[FileUtils (Commons IO 2.5-SNAPSHOT API)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File)

example
/src_directory_path/ is mount directory of remote server.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"hoge.txt\"");
    File srcFile = new File("/src_directory_path/hoge.txt");
    FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, resp.getOutputStream());
}
```

Was this by any chance what you wanted to hear?

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  InputStream in = new URL( "http://remote.file.url" ).openStream();
  IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

Comment: req and res parameters of doGet method must be request and response

Comment: Hi. AndroidCodeHunter. Thank you for your suggest.

Comment: If you would like user to be asked to save file rather than to display its content by browser add _attachment_ parameter: `resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"hoge.txt\"")`

Answer (score 3):

```
int BUFF_SIZE = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
File fileMp3 = new File("C:\Users\Ajay\*.mp3");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileMp3);
response.setContentType("audio/mpeg");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"hoge.txt\"");
response.setContentLength((int) fileMp3.length());
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

try {
    int byteRead = 0;
    while ((byteRead = fis.read()) != -1) {
       os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);

    }
    os.flush();
} catch (Exception excp) {
    downloadComplete = "-1";
    excp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    os.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to send a binary (mp3) file... will that work this way?

Comment: Thanks. Will test and let you know. BTW does it work for remote files?