# Why tomcat truncated my bytes output?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I wrote a servlet to serve a mp4 file.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.reset();
    resp.setContentType("video/mp4");

    Path f = Paths.get(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/small.mp4"));
    int length = (int) Files.size(f);
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(f);

    resp.setStatus(200);
    resp.setContentLength(length);

    ServletOutputStream sos = resp.getOutputStream();
    sos.write(bytes);
    resp.flushBuffer();
    sos.flush();
    sos.close();
}
```

The mp4 file is 1057148 bytes.
I captured the http messages using Charles and found the actual body size is less than the bytes I wrote. What's more strange is the actual entity bytes changed with different requests.

I don't know why tomcat truncate my output or what is something I missed.

My tomcat is apache-tomcat-8.0.27 on Mac OSX 10.11.2

---

Now I closed this question. I found the reason. Tomcat didn't truncate my response. That's Charles's problem. It showed: Client closed connection before receiving entire response.

So Charles seemed to have some bugs. I use Fiddler and found the response kept integrity as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java servlet read a file and send it as response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342457/java-servlet-read-a-file-and-send-it-as-response)

Comment: Move the line `resp.flushBuffer();` after `sos.close();` and try again. Furthermore, I strongly recommend you do not read the entire movie into memory. You will likely run out of memory with bigger movies.

Comment: My problem is why tomcat truncated my bytes rather than I don't know how to send a file

Comment: @Codo I know. But I just get a test rather than a production environment. And the file size is 1M. I followed you suggestion, but the truncation is still there.