# Download file or pdf in local system not only in server

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I written a code for downloading PDF using IText api ... i have implemented it in my project ..... i generated war file and deployed in tomcat server .... when i tried to download pdf it is downloading in server pc .... but it is not downloading in local pc when im taking server pc in local network...... Can any please help how to clear this....!

My code is like ... i'm creating folder then i'm saving in it

```
boolean folder= new File("C:\\Reports").mkdir();
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Reports\\somename.pdf"));                              Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
 document.open();
 document.close();
file.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am understanding your intention. You want client PC to access the server, and client PC download the said PDF to the specific directory?

From my understanding, it cannot be done with browser JS (I would imagine for security implications). You can prompt a file to be downloaded, but where it is saved depends on the user.

--
edit:

from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342457/java-servlet-read-a-file-and-send-it-as-response)

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"pdf.pdf\"");
    File srcFile = new File("C:/path_to_pdf/pdf.pdf");
    FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, resp.getOutputStream());
}
```

You will need FileUtils module.

Comment: Ya you are right from client PC i have to download file,but when i tried to download in client PC it is downloading in server PC itself

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe there are no way for browser JS to do file IO (I would imagine for security reasons). You might want to consider solving this problem differently.

e.g., writing an exe to run on the client PC

edit: alternatively, send the PDF file to the client, but they will have to choose where to save the said PDF

Comment: ya client has to choose where to save PDF but client will not run any exe , they will browse in browser by server PC ip address and port number (tomcat)

Comment: should i download fileutils jar

Comment: I am going to be honest, I work mainly with NodeJS, and I won't be surprised if there are more straight forward solutions. But FileUtils is something I would try if I am to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you give me another solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file to be transferred to the client then it seems that somewhere you will have to get the outputstream of the response object and send the pdf over that output stream.

At present your logic is just to create a pdf which it does on the local machine.

Some code like this needs to exist:

```
ServletOutputStream os= res.getOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, os);
```

Comment: OK but where should i mention save location path

Comment: just send the file over the servletoutputstream the client will take care of where to save the file on its machine

Comment: i didnt get u can u explain with brief ... Thank You

Comment: the server can only send the file. it cannot determine where the file will be saved on the client machine. the browser will receive the file over the network. the browser will determine where to save the file. it is not the job of the server to determine save location on client machine.

Comment: OK got it Thank You