# how to write header and records in csv file as response using java

Tags: java, file, csv, httpresponse

I am trying to download a csv file with the customized header and records in it. But i am not able to set header and fill the data in the csv file,  but it does append the source code of the same view page. I want the csv file as following ouput.

> `empId        EmpName          Designation`
>
> `101          John             Programmer`
>
> `102          Tom              Manager`

I am using the following code, it does not contain the code to write in the file. How can i achieve the expected output?

```
  try {
        response.reset();            
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String fileName =  "downloadEmployee.csv";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
                    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java servlet read a file and send it as response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342457/java-servlet-read-a-file-and-send-it-as-response)

Comment: my requirement is to download file with customised content suggest me except page view source how i can add my content to the page